# Locally store vimeo videos on my phone (Phonegap Build APP)

Tags: javascript, html, download, phonegap-build, vimeo

I have a problem with a mobile app that I'm developing in HTML, CSS and Javascript to compile with Phonegap.

What happens is that so far the videos have been playing from an iframe on Vimeo, but now it is necessary that they can be stored locally on the phone for offline playback.

Does anyone have an idea of ​​how could I do that? I do not know if with any API or with the native android player could be done.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: you can look into sd card libs, but this task is not going to be easy

Comment: I don't know what exactly you're asking for? At a first glance, Vimeo mentions an API wich should be able provide you all information you need to locate *(get/build the url)* the actual video-file that needs to be stored to disk. And [Download files and store them locally with Phonegap/jQuery Mobile Android and iOS Apps](//stackoverflow.com/q/6417055/6567275) is the result of a 2 second google search for "phonegap save video to disk"

Answer (score 2):

The following two conditions must be met to gain access to the `.mp4` video files.

1. You uploaded the videos (so you own them)
2. You are a [PRO](https://www.vimeo.com/pro) Vimeo user.

I haven't worked with Phonegap before but I have some perspective on Android. The easiest way to get the URL via Android code is through the the [Vimeo API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api). There is a Java library for interacting with the Vimeo API [here](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java) which will allow you to request `Video` objects for the videos you own (probably by hitting the `/me` endpoint).

[This](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java#how-do-i-play-a-video) section of the README.md should be helpful in understanding how to get access to fields on the `Video` object (but you should read the whole thing to get it set up).

Once you have a `Video` object, you can access the `download` field which is an array of `VideoFiles` which will contain a link to an `.mp4` file that you can pass to any file downloader. The code would look something like below:

```
Video myVideo = ...// Some video retrieved from the API
if(mVideo == null || mVideo.download == null || mVideo.download.isEmpty()) {
    // Throw an error
}
VideoFile videoFileToDownload = mVideo.get(0);
// The url to the mp4 file
String videoFileUrl = videoFileToDownload.mLink;
download(videoFileUrl); // You'll need to make a method to download
```

The two holes are 1) how to get a video and 2) how to download a file. The first question can be answered by the vimeo-networking-java library's README. The second question should be easy enough to find a solution on Google (downloading a file given a link to an .mp4 file).

Comment: Hello, it is a PRO account and owner of the videos, what can i do?

Comment: @AndrésGirón I just edited my answer to include more info. Please let me know if you have any questions.