# Vimeo offline video playback issue

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, vimeo

I’ve used `fijkplayer` library which is available on  flutter to play m3u8 videos.
Playing without download is working fine and the issue only happens when I trying to play downloaded videos. Also, I tried other libraries like `chewie`, `flutter_jikplayer`, `flutter_tencentplayer` but none of them worked.

This issue happens only on the  **hls links of Vimeo**. I’ve implemented everything using a public **hls** link available on the internet. After that, I found this bug.

This output seems to be a protocol related issue.

The xcode output is,

```
===== versions =====
ijkplayer    : f0.7.8
FFmpeg       : ff4.0--ijk0.8.25--20191031--001
libavutil    : 56.14.100
libavcodec   : 58.18.100
libavformat  : 58.12.100
libswscale   : 5.1.100
libswresample: 3.1.100
===== options =====
player-opts : overlay-format               = fcc-bgra
player-opts : videotoolbox                 = 1
player-opts : enable-position-notify       = 1
player-opts : start-on-prepared            = 1
format-opts : ijkapplication               = 4850081840
format-opts : ijkiomanager                 = 4849971424
===================
Opening 'https://46vod-adaptive.akamaized.net/exp=1597409385~acl=%2F04cf7e17-5507-416e-97c2-a26f6a27d395%2F%2A~hmac=2d7bd4c50e30032541752817b808bd618f7b0fff4a472e3d0b481f0aa2bd11f5/04cf7e17-5507-416e-97c2-a26f6a27d395/sep/audio/7724a1ec/playlist.m3u8' for reading
Protocol 'https' not on whitelist 'file,crypto'!

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0851E4DB-AA4C-4346-A6F2-5F2D00478D61/Documents/offline/+919744480203133/playlist.m3u8: Invalid argument
```

Let me know if anything is require, Will update here.

Comment: i dont know whether u came across this, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50455695/why-does-ffmpeg-ignore-protocol-whitelist-flag-when-converting-https-m3u8-stream

Comment: I've done this before in flutter_jikplayer as below

var option1 = IjkOption(IjkOptionCategory.format, "protocol_whitelist",
        "concat,http,tcp,https,tls,file");
    controller.setIjkPlayerOptions(
      [TargetPlatform.iOS, TargetPlatform.android],
      [option1].toSet(),
    );
But din't work for me

Comment: I tried accessing that link, it says permission denied. Your error message also says `crypto`, are you able to access this HLS link using a different client?

Comment: @BenButterworth Yes. It's working fine on HTML5 players, And it's also working on exoplayer.

Comment: use chewie with dispose or state management.

Answer (score 1):

The HLS files expire after a certain amount of time. So if you're downloading the `m3u8`, you're not actually downloading the video, just a link to the playlist/manifest file that tells the player where to pull the real (usually `mp4`) video files from. You can see [similar examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) with the M3U (this example links to `mp3` files, but `m3u8` usually links to `mp4` files).

So instead you'll want to download the *actual* `mp4` files from Vimeo and then pass those files to your player. I gave an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41991804/1759443) that talks through one way to do that. ([Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60767729/1759443) how to download with Flutter).

The links to the mp4 files expire as well. But if you download them before they expire, you can access them anytime from disk (using the local file URL).